# iOS get last 10 messaged contacts

Tags: ios, nsnotificationcenter, messageui, addressbookui

Is there a way to get the last 10 messaged(sms) contacts in your app? 
I want to be able append a list of favs or the most recent messaged contacts to my app. I have looked into NSNotification center and couldn't seem to find a way for this. Is there another way or something I am missing in searching?

Any advise on this? 
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible, Apple does not allow access to these kinds of data. You can NOT access message, call list or any or private data.